# How to remove trailing whitespaces at the end of each line?

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I am trying a Challenge in Dcoder and my answer is same to the expected output however I am thinking that the problem is about the given situation to remove the trailing whitespaces at the end of each line.

To make it clear, this is the problem:

> You need to print this pattern up to `N`, e.g. `N = 3`
>
> Expected Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> 1 2
> 1 2 3
> ```
>
> Do not leave trailing spaces at the end of each line!

This is my Code:

```
String sp = " ";
for (int rows = 1; rows <= range; rows++) { //rows
    for (int cols = 1; cols <= rows; cols++) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toString(cols) + sp);
    }
    System.out.println(sp.trim());
}
```

I tried concatenating `Integer.toString(cols)` and `sp` then another `sp.trim()` output is also the same but challenge doesn't say that its correct, why is this happening? Can anybody explain or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the whitespace `sp` after every number in your second `for` loop. That's why there is a trailing whitespace when you print out the lines.

You have several options, like using a `StringBuilder` and `.append()` the values and then print `toString().trim()`, but here's a very simple extension of your code where I just hard-coded the `range` by `4`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sp = " ";

    for (int rows = 1; rows <= 4; rows++) {
        for (int cols = 1; cols <= rows; cols++) {
            // here you need to find out if it is the last number to be printed
            if (cols == rows) {
                // if it is, just print that number
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(cols));
            } else {
                // otherwise print the number and the whitespace
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(cols) + sp);
            }
        }
        // force a linebreak
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Alternative solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int rows = 1; rows <= 4; rows++) {
        StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cols = 1; cols <= rows; cols++) {
            if (cols == rows) {
                lineBuilder.append(Integer.toString(cols));
            } else {
                lineBuilder.append(Integer.toString(cols)).append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lineBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang it. Haha. I am trying to use charAt and converting it. And the code was just so simple? Ahhaah I see, It's been a long time since I last programmed. Thanks a lot! I learned my mistake dang it!  Thanks thanks. It worked.

Comment: But Im kinda curious to make it by using charAt is it possible? But I guess that is much easier.

Comment: @user13216654 What exactly are you targeting? The removal of the trailing whitespace? **I don't think that** **(1.)** removing a trailing whitespace is a better idea than not appending it in the first place, **(2.)** `charAt()` would be a good choice for removing a character when there's `String.substring()` and `StringBuilder.removeCharAt()` and **(3.)** there is no need for creating a `String` as long as you just want to print simple lines.

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
int range = 3;
for(int rows = 1; rows <= range; rows++ ) {
    for(int cols = 1; cols <= rows; cols++ ) {
        if (cols == rows) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(cols));
        } else {
            System.out.print(Integer.toString(cols) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sp = " ";
for (int rows = 1; rows <= 3; rows++){ //rows
 
    String pattern ="";
    for (int cols = 1; cols <= rows; cols++)
        pattern += Integer.toString(cols) + sp;

    System.out.println(pattern.trim());
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26551437)

Comment: @SSP, it does answer to the question.  Can you please elaborate on how can i improve it since i'm still new here.  Thanks.

Comment: To improve this answer include some explanation of how and why it works. Pretend you are walking someone through your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 8* you can use [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) method to concatenate strings with whitespaces *in between*:

```java
int n = 5;
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
        // row of numbers
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i)
                // number as string
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                // join strings into one line
                // with spaces in between
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        // output line by line
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method with the same effect:

```java
int n = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // row of numbers
    String[] row = new String[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        // number as string
        row[j] = String.valueOf(j + 1);
    }
    // join an array of strings into
    // one line with spaces in between
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", row));
}
```

Output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

---

<sup>See also: [Adding a whitespace inside a List of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658156/15402945)</sup>