# Adding a whitespace inside a List of strings?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, character, whitespace

I have an `ArrayList` of strings which contains different words. What I am trying to do is to add whitespace inside the list between each word.

My code does print out the elements with whitespace, but as printout only, I need the whitespace to be included in the list so I can use it as a value.

Example input: `Hi, how are you?`, result: `Hi,", " ", "are", " ", "you?`

```java
public void getCipher(ArrayList<String> list) {
    String regex = "\", \" " + "\", " + "\"";
    for (String input : list) {
        String newResult = input + regex;
        System.out.print(newResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the list and update each string in it with the new string as shown below:

```
public List<String> updateStrings(List<String> list) {
    String regex = "\", \" " + "\", " + "\"";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, list.get(i) + regex);

    }
    return list;
}
```

**[Test it online:](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/aun)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Hello", "World"));
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(updateStrings(list));
    }

    static List<String> updateStrings(List<String> list) {
        String regex = "\", \" " + "\", " + "\"";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.set(i, list.get(i) + regex);

        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello, World]
[Hello", " ", ", World", " ", "]
```

[image]

Comment: thats great but I also have a problem with regex, I want my output to be covered with quotation marks for each word from beginning to end with empty spaces. like "Hello", " ", "World".

Comment: @Waelalmerri - In that case, you can do it as `String regex = "\", \" \"";
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   list.set(i, "\"" + list.get(i) + regex);

  }`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 1):

To add spaces between other items in a list, I would create a new list and iterate over the "old" one, like so:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCipher(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String regex = "\", \" " + "\", "+ "\"";
    for (String input : list) {
        result.add(input + regex);
        result.add(" ");
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can set your list to the result of this method, like

```
list = getCipher(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method to insert whitespaces between the elements in the list:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("Hi,", "how", "are", "you?");
    System.out.println(appendSpaces(list));
}
```

```java
public static List<String> appendSpaces(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            // append a space before each word
            .flatMap(str -> Stream.of(" ", str))
            // skip first space
            .skip(1)
            // return list
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Output:

```
[Hi,,  , how,  , are,  , you?]
```

Screenshot from idea:

[image: screenshot from idea]

---

<sup>See also: [How to add characters in the middle of a word in an arraylist in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66645310/15402945)</sup>